# Flexibility of the Newton Fellowship?

Tags: job-search, postdocs, funding

I'm graduating this summer (2014) and trying to find a job in the UK so I can go live with my husband. I am thinking of applying for the Newton Fellowship, however, they have a really strange schedule and timing. That is, I wouldn't find out about the award until late October, and the position wouldn't start until January 2015. That would leave me with an awkward six months without a job or funding, unless I managed to get a short-term job. I've decided to start applying for other positions (lectureships and funded post-docs) with an eye toward the more immediate future and because the Newton is very competitive.

My questions are:

- what happens if I take a 1-2 year post-doc offer and then find out I am awarded the fellowship?
- Am I allowed to use the funds wherever I am?
- If I accept a job-offer do I have to notify the fellowship and withdraw my application?

Comment: Nobody expects anyone to apply for a very competitive fellowship as their one and only job prospect.  I can't offer any advice beyond this, as I know nothing about the Newton Fellowship specifically.

Comment: Note that the deadline for the 2014 is already passed, but the answers can be useful to the next round.

Comment: Just to follow up, I did apply to the grant but I ended up taking a faculty position for this coming fall, so I will update this post when I hear back about the Newton Fellowship in October.

Comment: Newton is extremely competitive. You better be extremely successful so far...

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting it after all! And my current University is letting me take the fellowship (at another university) and I can come back to my faculty position after. Very happy with the deal even though it means half the pay.